# Separate text in faceted ggplot boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-text

how can I separate the text annotations inserted by geom_text in the following boxplots?

```
data(mtcars)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(as.factor(vs), mpg, color = am )) +
facet_wrap(~gear) +
geom_boxplot() +
geom_text(data=mtcars, aes(x=0.7, y = 30, label=carb), parse=TRUE)
```

This is just an example, not the real problem I have. In my specific case, the text annotations indicate the amount of observations in the respective group. They come from an aggregate function.
At the end I would like to have faceted boxplots as in the example, with the respective number of observations above each respective boxplot.

Comment: would something like this work for you: library(ggrepel); data(mtcars)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(as.factor(vs), mpg, color = am )) +
facet_wrap(~gear) +
geom_boxplot() +
geom_text_repel(data=mtcars, aes(x=0.7, y = 30, label=carb), parse=TRUE)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This solution works, but it is not ideal, since geom_text_repel randomly decides where it puts the texts. They are separated now, so it is better than previously. Still, if there is a way to allocate the texts freely, this would be even better.

Comment: using geom_text(), you could create a new dataset and add "freely" your  text

Comment: You are right. I had this idea but did not think it through. Now I did, and it works fine. Thank you very much!